# Creating a grid layout for images

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm trying to design a layout of images / divs like the following using HTML & CSS.

[image]

Here's my attempt:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="bigBox">
   </div>
 <div class="box 1"></div>
 <div class="box 2"></div>
 <div class="box 3"></div>
 <div class="box 4"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 415px;
}

.bigBox {
float: left;
width: 400px;
height: 290px;
}

.box {
width: 244px;
height: 200px;
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.1 { background: url("http://i.imgur.com/zYerntp.png"); background-color: red;}
```

However, obviously the code is not working how I expected it to be, I've tried puting the container inside relative positioning with the elements inside as absolute but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a table would be the most structured, like in @user1925801's answer, I'd say this is easier just using classes and CSS to style. All you'd have to do is float all the boxes to the right, and add certain classes to style them, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="big orange"></div>
<div class="small blue"></div>
<div class="small red"></div>
<div class="small red"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

/* sizes */
.big {
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
}
.small {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
}

/* colors */
.orange {
    background-color: orange;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This outputs:

[image]

See a working example [at JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/goc3jvqg/).

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this layout with CSS [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container-outer">
    <div class="bigBox"></div>
    <div id="container-inner">
        <div class="box a"></div>
        <div class="box b"></div>
        <div class="box c"></div>
        <div class="box d"></div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container-outer {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
}

.bigBox {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: orangered;
}

#container-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
    width: 244px;
    height: 150px;
}

.a, .d { background-color: skyblue; }
.b, .c { background-color: red; }
```

[image]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qjok9104/)

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: [Cross-browser inclusion](http://jsfiddle.net/qjok9104/1/) - just added `webkit` prefixes